# Reset Observable.timer()

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've try to make my Timer but , have got one problem I couldn't understand how to reset(refresh) my timer.

```
startTimer() {
Observable.timer(this.countDownDuration, 1000)
        .map(i => this.countDownDuration - i)
        .take(this.countDownDuration + 1)
        .subscribe(i => {
          this.countDown = i;
          console.log(this.countDown);
        });
}

resetTimer() {
  must stop previous timer and start new 
}
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

```
const s = new BehaviorSubject(null);

s.switchMap(() => Observable.timer(this.countDownDuration, 1000))
  .map(...)
  ...
  .subscribe(...);

resetTimer() {
  s.next();
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me. If I click on reset after the timer finished, it doesn't reset. If I click while the timer is counting, it resets but it doesn't count down to zero: http://embed.plnkr.co/ZA8Q9ufBkFpXdOEii5eP/

Comment: It won't work if you use `take` because it completes the chain and unsubscribes.

Answer (score 0):

I found some another way for this.
And in my example I must use take.
I know how to reset throw switchMap.
But it's not good for me.
May be it'is not good decision.

```
status;

startTimer() {
this.status = Observable.timer(this.countDownDuration, 1000)
        .map(i => this.countDownDuration - i)
        .take(this.countDownDuration + 1)
        .subscribe(i => {
          this.countDown = i;
          console.log(this.countDown);
        });
}

resetTimer() {
  this.status.unsubscribe(); 
  this.startTimer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The martin's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51726532/3024975) is correct, but I don't like subscribing the BehaviorSubject. So this is an alternative:

We need a way to sinal the Observable to restart itself. This is a good use case for `Subject`

```
const signal = new Subject();

Observable.defer(() => Observable.timer(this.countDownDuration, 1000))
  .takeUntil(signal)
  .repeat()
  .map(....)
  .subscribe(...);

resetTimer() {
  signal.next();
}
```

I use [takeUntil](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeUntil) to stop the Observable and immediately repeat it using [repeat](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-repeat). [defer](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer) is used to create timer with new `this.countDownDuration` value (I expect it's going to change).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```
  recording$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  stopWatch$: Observable<number>;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.stopWatch$ = this.recording$.pipe(
      switchMap(r => r ? timer(0, 10) : never()),
      share()
    );

  }

  start() {
    this.recording$.next(true);
  }

  stop() {
    this.recording$.next(false);
  }
```